# Act as Votable - List who voted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, voting-system

I've been using the [act as votable gem](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) and so far it's been working great.

However I'm wondering if there's a way to create a list of who voted on the votable item? Say I have a blog post that users can vote on. I'd like to be able to click on the number of favorites and get a list of all voters who voted up on the post.

I thought about creating another table with a blog post reference ID and a user ID, and adding an entry to that table every time the like method was called. But I was hoping there would be an easier way to accomplish this with the gem.

Answer (score 2):

```
@user  = @post.votes_for.up.by_type(User).voters
```

Add this line in your post controller to get who has voted up on the post(blog)
& then in the User Model add

```
acts_as_voter
```